# Html : PHP, C# and JS formatter

Tags: c#, php, javascript, jquery, html

Im looking for something like this

http://ycouriel.blogspot.nl/2010/02/add-c-code-formatter-widget-to-your.html

But then a library that can format PHP, C# and Javascript

If there are no solutions like that, does anyone know Where i can find a JS & PHP version of the above script?

Been digging for hours now... so any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: **What**?.... #1: I am not even sure what you are asking. #2: **No** shopping questions on Stack Overflow are allowed...

Comment: Its not shopping, its asking for help. Im asking if anyone knows of PHP version of the above or has a sollution for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a js library which supports 54 programming languages. [HIGHLIGHT.JS](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)